# while do doesn't work in a bash script on AIX

Tags: bash, aix

I'm building a script that uses a while loop like the following:

```
$sync=0
while [ $sync -eq 0 ];
do
body of the loop where $sync get changed sevaral times


done
```

The probleme is when I execute the script it gives me an error saying:

```
enter code hereline 53: 0=0: command not found
```

Please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: `$sync=0` in the beginning must be `sync=0`

Answer (score 2):

Change `$sync=0` to `sync=0`. bash is not perl, so don't use the `$` when assigning to a variable.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters

PS, the error message is useful: what is on line 53 in your script?

Comment: I'v changed $sync=0 to sync=0, but the problem persist.

Comment: Thanks gys problem solved, I was adding "$" not only before the while loop but also in the loop body.

Thanks floks very much :)